# How to configure company email such as dd@.ac.tz for sending email for laravel application?

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLHbR.png)How to configure company email for sending email to user in laravel.

Comment: `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`? you can also set the sender address through code, please check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#configuring-the-sender). do remember though, your smtp server should be trusted enough to send that email otherwise your email may end up on spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on sending e-mails from the same address globally, you can set it up in config/mail.php through .env file

```
MAIL_FROM=dd@.ac.tz
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=dd@.ac.tz
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Your company name"
```